# What could be the applications of Damped Oscillation?

Tags: friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I've been researching on [Damped Oscillation](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=damped+harmonic+oscillator) for a few days for a research paper, however I couldn't find any of its applications on the web, though there are few examples of it, but they couldn't be considered as applications. So, I would be thankful if anyone can anyone tell me about some of its applications.

Comment: What Google searches have you done to find anything about this?

Comment: @kyle Would be better if you could instead find from Google and paste ot here, instead of rating the question negative. -_-

Comment: I'm not willing to do a search that you can clearly do yourself.

Comment: *"however I couldn't find any of its applications on the web"*  Do you play guitar?  Piano?

Comment: Electronic Tom-Tom. Doesn't even sound half bad: http://www.simplecircuitdiagram.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/ELECTRONIC-DRUM.gif.It's also look for "regenerative receivers": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_circuit

Answer (score 2):

every system that oscillated and that should not osscillated would be an application for damped oscillation. There are many examples in control engineering, but to give you a more daily concurrent example: car shock absorbers. If you drive along a road and hit a chuckhole you don't want your car to jump up and down for half a minute. Since car shock absorbers are just a feather-mass-system it would take a while to stop the jumping (without damping).

Edit: @ sean Sorry i am not a native english speaker. I just let the word translate by a website and took the wrong one from the suggested. Thanks for pointing it out, I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: You say bumper but in your example it seems like you're talking about shock absorbers and struts.